# Stream audio commands from Android to Ubuntu and back via Bluetooth

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, bluetooth

I have a college assignment to build Android app that communicates with Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution), and streams audio via microphone and speakers both on PC and phone. Switching the direction of communication should be done on Android and script for listening on Bluetooth port on PC should be written in Python or some other lightweight language.  It does not have to be full-duplex, only single-duplex.

Is the answer in the BluetoothA2dp Android profile or is there something else?

I'm common with making simple Android apps.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer, but I am working on something similar.
Basically working with python on windows platform to record streaming audio from microphone of laptop then process the sound for ANC [ automatic noise cancellation ] and pass it through band-pass filter then output the audio stream to a Bluetooth device.
I would like to ultimately port this to smartphone, but for now prototyping with Python as that's  lot easier.

While I am still early stage on the project, here are two piceses that may be helpful,

## 1) Stream Audio from microphone to speakers using  sounddevice

Record external Audio and play back

Refer to soundaudio module installation details from here

http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.1/

```
import sounddevice as sd
duration = 5  # seconds

myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float64')

print "Recording Audio"
sd.wait()

print "Audio recording complete , Play Audio"
sd.play(myrecording, fs)

sd.wait()
print "Play Audio Complete"
```

## 2)Communicate to bluetooth

Refer to details from here:

https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html

```
    import bluetooth
    target_name = "My Phone"
    target_address = None
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
target_address = bdaddr
break


if target_address is not None:
    print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
else:
    print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"

I know I am simply quoting examples from these sites, You may refer to these sites to gain more insight.

Once I have a working prototype I will try to post it here in future.